# Regex - searching similar country names in text

Tags: python, regex

I want to identify the countries that appear in a text from a *list of pre-defined countries*.
Problem is, some names are very similar, so if one country is in the text it will also identify the other.
For example:

```
text1 = "The disease has spread to three countries: Guinea, Guinea-Bassau and Equatorial Guinea."

text2 = "Only Guinea-Bassau and Equatorial Guinea contained strains of the virus."

list_of_countries = ['Guinea', 'Guinea-Bassau', 'Equatorial Guinea']
```

I still haven't figured out a code that would return all three list items for text1, but only 'Guinea-Bassau' and 'Equatorial Guinea' for text2.

This is just a specific example. I can of course create an ad-hoc solution for the specific problem of the 3 Guinea-containing countries in Africa, but then the problem would return for "Republic of the Congo" and "Democratic Republic of the Congo", etc.

EDIT: It occurs to me that one way to tackle this problem would be to delete/discard of any instance in text once it matches the longest-named country possible.

Comment: @jdehesa Right, whitespace boundaries won't work here. @Desperate, try [this solution](https://ideone.com/ivaIES): `list_of_countries=sorted(list_of_countries,key=len,reverse=True)` => `rx=r'\b(?:{})\b'.format("|".join(list_of_countries))` => `print(re.findall(rx, text1))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah I see, that's great. It seems to work without sorting the list? It even works in more complicated cases like [this](https://ideone.com/LFLTgA).

Comment: A well constructed regex solution will return the longest match and will not return overlapping matches anyway. If you are trying to solve this with regular expressions, **show us your regexp.** Edit it into the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution worked perfectly, thank you. I was not aware of the (?:..) option in regex.

Comment: @Knowname I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53515458/3832970) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

text1 = "The disease has spread to three countries: Guinea, Guinea-Bassau and Equatorial Guinea."
text2 = "Only Guinea-Bassau and Equatorial Guinea contained strains of the virus."
list_of_countries = ['Guinea', 'Guinea-Bassau', 'Equatorial Guinea']

# Sort the list by length in descending order
list_of_countries=sorted(list_of_countries,key=len,reverse=True)
# Build the alternation based regex with \b to match each item as a whole word 
rx=r'\b(?:{})\b'.format("|".join(list_of_countries))
print(re.findall(rx, text1))
# => ['Guinea', 'Guinea-Bassau', 'Equatorial Guinea']
print(re.findall(rx, text2))
# => ['Guinea-Bassau', 'Equatorial Guinea']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ivaIES)

Note that sorting the `list_of_countries` list by length in descending order **is important** because the items in the list may have whitespace and might start at the same position in the string.

The regex formed is

```
\b(?:Equatorial Guinea|Guinea-Bassau|Guinea)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Y1AB4/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group so that word boundaries could be applied to each alterntive

  - `Equatorial Guinea`
  - `|` - or
  - `Guinea-Bassau`
  - `|`  - or
  - `Guinea`
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: FYI: [Here](https://ideone.com/8KjvdM) is an example with `Guinea` and `Guinea Bassau` (I removed the hyphen to showcase the problem) in the country list and text. Note how `Bassau` goes missing in the resulting list.